# IP forwarding does not work

Tags: firewall, ip, router, gateway

I have 2 Ubuntu systems , both have Ubuntu 20.04, one has server (5.4.0-42-generic) , the other has desktop (5.4.0-58-generic).
I can get ip forwarding working on one system which has the server .
But I can't get it to work on the other system which has desktop.
The network configuration is the same on the system which is able to forwards packets and the one which does not.

I have checked that

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1

I have flushed iptables using
iptables -F

ufw is inactive

I can ping both interfaces of the router from either side, so I think the routing table on the hosts on either side is correct.
I can also ping the interfaces  on the hosts on either side from the router, so I think the routing table on the router is correct.
I have disabled NetworkManager; am using networkd in /etc/netplan/*yaml

Any suggestions on how to debug this ?

Comment: We need more details. What port is being forwarded and from where to where, for each of the two setups?

Comment: There is no NAT involved, so all IP packets should be forwarded. One interface is 192.168.1.1 and other interface is 192.168.2.1. There is a host on one side 192.168.1.2 and on the other side 192.168.2.2. Only ping is used to check if packets are being forwarded from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.2.2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

if iptable `FORWARD` policy is not set to `ACCEPT`.

```
$ sudo iptables --list


Chain FORWARD (policy DROP) <-- HERE
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Change it to `ACCEPT`.

```
sudo iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT
```

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Sometimes that could be the issue, even when ipv4 forwarding is enabled

Comment: Not an answer. This is a comment answers do not contain statements like try this, or maybe or any other sort of phrase.

Comment: Setting this policy to `ACCEPT` is a huge security impact.